Highlighting on lists of strings and lists of numbers in a listing
I am following the format used by this answer to color a json listing on my document, but I noticed that in a list of strings and a list of numbers, only the first element gets colored properly. Is there a way I can change the definition to fix that?
The example modified to use the failing items:
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\jsonkey{\color{purple}}
\newcommand\jsonvalue{\color{cyan}}
\newcommand\jsonnumber{\color{orange}}

% switch used as state variable
\makeatletter
\newif\ifisvalue@json

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    tabsize             = 4,
    showstringspaces    = false,
    keywords            = {false,true},
    alsoletter          = 0123456789.,
    morestring          = [s]{"}{"},
    stringstyle         = \jsonkey\ifisvalue@json\jsonvalue\fi,
    MoreSelectCharTable = \lst@DefSaveDef{`:}\colon@json{\enterMode@json},
    MoreSelectCharTable = \lst@DefSaveDef{`,}\comma@json{\exitMode@json{\comma@json}},
    MoreSelectCharTable = \lst@DefSaveDef{`\{}\bracket@json{\exitMode@json{\bracket@json}},
    basicstyle          = \ttfamily
}

% enter "value" mode after encountering a colon
\newcommand\enterMode@json{%
    \colon@json%
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
        \global\isvalue@jsontrue%
    \fi
}

% leave "value" mode: either we hit a comma, or the value is a nested object
\newcommand\exitMode@json[1]{#1\global\isvalue@jsonfalse}

\lst@AddToHook{Output}{%
    \ifisvalue@json%
        \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
            \def\lst@thestyle{\jsonnumber}%
        \fi
    \fi
    %override by keyword style if a keyword is detected!
    \lsthk@DetectKeywords% 
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A complex example}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=json] 
{
    "string": [
        “Test1”,
        “Test2”,
    ],
    "numbers": [0, …, 10],
    "name":
        "test"
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Do you have to use listings? If not, consider switching to minted

@DG' I am using the lstlistings table of contents and importing a code file. I really want to stay in the listings environment

You can do AFIK anything with minted what you can do with listings. I wrote up how as an answer anyway. Also have a look at the docs: https://ctan.org/pkg/minted

You could use minted instead of listings:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\section{A complex example}

\usemintedstyle{friendly}
\inputminted{json}{test.json}

\end{document}

Where test.json contains:
{
    "string": [
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
    ],
    "numbers": [0, …, 10],
    "name":
        "test"
}

You need to call latex with --shell-escape. The output looks like this:

This example is rendered with the style friendly, you can browse and test the other available styles here: https://pygments.org/demo/

I have a custom Table of Contents that works with \lstinputlisting that I can’t use with this though. Is there a way to do it with listings or should I figure out a way to get a table of contents for the minted inputs?

Minted knows the command \listoflistings, just check the excellent manual. But maybe it doesn't do what you want, hard to tell without the code. My guess is that it's easier to tweak minted, than writing the commands that lets listings parse json arrays correctly . . . however, I'd love to see a listings solution!
